How to have a Separate Google Sheet transfer data to another Google Sheet?

Have One Google Sheet where staff can only View
Have One google Sheet where Admin can type and edit while it transfers the data to that view only google sheet.

I am trying to have the data transfer from one sheet to a completely separate sheet if possible without copy and paste. I am wondering how to get this done, if possible. I know it seems strange but if anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Transfer data from one Google Sheet to a different Google Sheet
Transferring data from one Google Sheet to another is possible using Google Apps Script. I have created an Admin Sheet where all updates made will be reflected in another sheet named 'View Only'.
In the Admin Sheet, open the Apps Script editor and input the following code:
function onEdit(e) {
  var adminSheetName = 'Admin'; // Name of the sheet in the Admin Sheet
  var viewOnlySheetId = '1lLCFqd0iniHlb8z_uGWB4mIlii4hcBkkfXA8Sw8WlAM'; // Replace with the ID of the View-Only Sheet
  var viewOnlySheetName = 'View Only'; // Name of the sheet in the View-Only Sheet

  // Get the edited sheet
  var editedSheet = e.source.getSheetByName(adminSheetName);
  if (e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() !== adminSheetName) return;

  // Get the data range and values
  var dataRange = editedSheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // Open the View-Only Sheet
  var viewSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(viewOnlySheetId).getSheetByName(viewOnlySheetName);

  // Clear the existing data and set new values
  viewSheet.clear(); // Clears existing data
  viewSheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}

function setupTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEdit')
    .forSpreadsheet(ss)
    .onEdit()
    .create();
}

 

Also, don't forget to set up the trigger in Apps Script so that any changes automatically update the other sheet.
Here is the guide to set up triggers:
1.) Click on triggers (Clock icon on the left side of your screen)
2.) Click "Add Triggers"

Sample Output:


Reference/s:
Simple Triggers
Installable Triggers
Class Spreadsheet

Hello thanks for this response, what about if I wanted to add it to a certain sub sheet ( the sheets on the bottom of the page where you press + and rename)
